# Generator variable can’t be used more than once

Tags: python

### Python loop generator

Looks like I’m missing something with for loop generators…

I deliberately made this simple code to test what was happening when I converted my list comprehensions to generators.

It showed that the generator var can’t be used more than once:

```py
lst = [1,2,3]

plus = (i+1 for i in lst)

for i in plus: 
    print(i)
    
for i in plus:
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
2
3
4
```

#### What I expected:

It outputs the above twice.

#### What I want to know:

What is the reason for the generator var only being usable once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main purpose of using a generator rather than a list or other data structure is to *conserve memory*. Having a piece of code and an instruction pointer that computes values on demand saves you the space to store all those values simultaneously.

But the computation that creates the values might have side effects (and in fact, it usually has). It's not possible in general to ensure that running the code a second time would result in exactly the same outputs. The alternative would be to store the values as they are generated, but that would defeat the entire purpose of using a generator in the first place!

Therefore, if you want to use the results of a generator several times, the correct thing to do is simply to turn it into a list first by saying

```
plus = list(plus)
```

and then you can compute to your heart's content without hitting this limitation.

Comment: thank you, so it seems a generator shouldn’t even be used as a var

Comment: That's my opinion, too - I ran into this problem many times while learning advanced Python, and as far as I can tell it's never a good reason to store a generator. Sooner or later you *will* forget that it's a generator and treat it like a list, and things start failing subtly.

Comment: Yeah and working around it by using ```var = list(gen)``` just seems like a long way to do a list comprehension but the speed boost from the generator is very good from now on I’m just going to use it when I’m doing something once